# JavaScript Saving this. variable inside of image.onLoad

Tags: javascript, object

```
function InfoImage(path,title){
    this.path = path;
    this.title = title;
    this.color = undefined;
    this.maxPixels = undefined;

    this.init = function(){
        var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        var img_Color = new Image_Processing_Color(canvas);
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            img_Color.init(img);
            this.color = img_Color.getDominantColor(); //this doesnt work
            this.maxPixels = img_Color.getDominantColorPixels();
        };
        img.src = path;
    };


    this.init();
}
```

With this example, how can i save those variables as InfoImage variable?  I know that using `this` there will affect Image and not InfoImage...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, the usual answer is to use a variable to refer to `this`, which `init` then closes over:

```
function InfoImage(path,title){
    this.path = path;
    this.title = title;
    this.color = undefined;
    this.maxPixels = undefined;

    this.init = function(){
        var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        var img_Color = new Image_Processing_Color(canvas);
        var img = new Image();
        var infoimg = this;                                         // <===

        img.onload = function () {
            img_Color.init(img);
            infoimg.color = img_Color.getDominantColor();           // <===
            infoimg.maxPixels = img_Color.getDominantColorPixels(); // <===
        };
        img.src = path;
    };
}
```

You can also use [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5):

```
function InfoImage(path,title){
    this.path = path;
    this.title = title;
    this.color = undefined;
    this.maxPixels = undefined;

    this.init = function(){
        var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        var img_Color = new Image_Processing_Color(canvas);
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function () {
            img_Color.init(img);
            this.color = img_Color.getDominantColor();
            this.maxPixels = img_Color.getDominantColorPixels();
        }.bind(this);                                             // <===
        img.src = path;
    };
}
```

With ES6, the next version of JavaScript, you'll be able to use an arrow function, because unlike normal functions, arrow functions inherit their `this` value from the context in which they're defined:

```
function InfoImage(path,title){
    this.path = path;
    this.title = title;
    this.color = undefined;
    this.maxPixels = undefined;

    this.init = function(){
        var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        var img_Color = new Image_Processing_Color(canvas);
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = () => {                              // <===
            img_Color.init(img);
            this.color = img_Color.getDominantColor();
            this.maxPixels = img_Color.getDominantColorPixels();
        };
        img.src = path;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the `this` and `that` pattern:

```
function InfoImage(path, title) {
    var _this = this;
    this.init = function(){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            _this.color = img_Color.getDominantColor();
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function InfoImage(path,title){
    var self = this;

    this.path = path;
    this.title = title;
    this.color = undefined;
    this.maxPixels = undefined;

    this.init = function(){
        var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        var img_Color = new Image_Processing_Color(canvas);
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            img_Color.init(img);
            self.color = img_Color.getDominantColor(); //this doesnt work
            self.maxPixels = img_Color.getDominantColorPixels();
        };
        img.src = path;
    };

    this.init();
}
```

It's that easy. `this` is a keyword and depends on the function's binded calling context, but it can be stored to a variable just like anything else in JavaScript.