# Gain the length and width of the image in angular (from component)

Tags: html, angular, image, typescript, width

I want to get the length and width of a picture I uploaded and its base64 is.
This is my code :

```
Image img = new Image();
img.src = Selectedimage.src;
Img.onload = function {
this.width = img.width;
this.height = img.height; }
```

The problem is that I do not have access to the variables in this class through «this».
Someone knows what the problem is, or is there another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Saving this. variable inside of image.onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824756/javascript-saving-this-variable-inside-of-image-onload)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your issue is you cannot access `width` and `height` using `this` inside `Img.onload` function because it is in another `scope`. Try as follows:

```
var self = this;
Img.onload = function {
    self.width = img.width;
    self.height = img.height; 
}
```

Comment: update your question with more details. I mean more code. It is better if you can create stackblitz

Comment: I checked again, replied ... The problem was that it does not return the length and width itself ... To get the length and width of another way?
The image format is also Base64.